# Where does Windows drag'n'drop store dragged item data?

Tags: windows

It's not (visibly) using the clipboard because it doesn't trash the clipboard contents... where does it go?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's up to the application. Typically nothing much happens  during dragging, except for working out if the drag is over a suitable drop target. When the item is dropped, the target handles the drop event somehow, but it doesn't have to store anything anywhere.

Comment: But surely the whole point is there's a standard mechanism, so you can drag text from Firefox -> Word, etc?

Comment: @John As Preet points out, it is up to Word to ask Firefox for the data somehow.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect most applictions will be using COM Drag and drop and this doesn't need a store. The sender just calls a methods on the reciever and it collects the data directly from the sender.